# How to get correct time on client side javascript?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, datetime

Currently, I have  a datetime field in one of my sqlserver table.
And I Query (`SELECT Column1, myDateField FROM MyTimeTable BETWEEN @startDate AND @endDate`).
NOW I got `Column1, myDateField` at C# code side using Entity framework.

## Problem

Then I'm passing these dates to client side as json. Now, asp.net converts date to `"\/Date(1410588000000)\/"` format. (ie date '19-9-2014' to `1410588000000`). When I create date with this ticks (From 1970 ticks of javascript) it will add extra 5.00 hours (server timezone is -5.00). This happens because while converting datetime to `"\/Date(xxxxxxxxx)\/"` format, .net consider the date in database (ie, now a c# datetime using entity framework) is local (-5.00). So it creates ticks for +5.00 hours. How can I convince .net that the time is in utc?

Comment: Have you tried "new DateTime(1410588000000, DateTimeKind.Utc)" this?

Answer (score 1):

Please convert your DATE TIME to any fixed specific format and than follow it every where,
So it will help you to maintain the consistency.

**Write query like below**

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),GETDATE(),113) AS DateConvert;
```

Format will be "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss:zzz"
this will send exact date time format , which will be converted easily.
Hope this will help you.

Now we can use DateTime.ParseExact to convert received string (Date) to DateTime

C# code

```
  String dateString = "01 Jun 2008 08:30:06:00";
  CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;
  String format = "dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss:zzz";
  try {
     DateTime result = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
  }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
Var date = new Date();
```

now the date have the value of client's time.

```js
alert(new Date());
```